# running a python script where dependencies are not avail: distributed computing

Tags: python, distributed

I have access to a grid (running condor) that would (potentially) allow to very substantially reduce how long by nltk based nlp tasks take. unfortunately, i dont have root access on the cluster so cannot install new packages, only run whatever is available on the linux boxes.

python is of course available, but nltk isnt - i was wondering however, if there might be a way around this somehow ? is there a way i can somehow still distribute the task in a self-contained 'package' of some sort?

Thanks for your hel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get a standard user account, you could use [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to create a sandbox in that user-account, where you can install nltk.

Comment: i found this: maybe i've grabbed the wrong end of the stick, but seems like what i would need? unfortunately we dont have virtualenv, and looks like a need a sudo easy_install ..

Comment: I haven't worked with it extensively in this mode, but you can use `virtualenv` without installing: just extract the zip file and then you can use `python virtualenv.py ENV` the same way you would use `virtualenv ENV`.